# XCode 4 not detect iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have iPad 1 and i want to test my app on it.

i connect the iPad to the computer, and the `IOS Device` not change to the device name.
when i press on Run i get this msg:

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. 
Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your 
application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.
```

Any suggestion why it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top explanations for this error are

1) Your iPad is running an OS version newer than that supported by Xcode

or

2) You have not yet provisioned your iPad

Comment: ipad is 4.3.3 and i have provision for this ipad

Answer (score 1):

Ok

I find the solution :
in `IOS Deployment Target` change it to the minimum version you want the app will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the UDID of the device to your developer mobile provisioning profile.
If you have Xcode 4.2 this can be done actually automatically, else you'll have to do this manually (get the UDID, log into the developer portal, add the device's UDID to the devices list, at that device then to your developer profile, download and install that profile, select this profile as a developer profile for your current app)